# How to construct a Hibernate query for generating time-series graph data

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

There exists a Hibernate entity

```
WeatherStatistic
```

which contains snapshots of atmospheric data at given times.

If the WeatherStatistic had only 1 type of atmospheric measurement, eg. temperature:

```
| time   | temperature |  
 -------- -------------   
| 09:00  |    10       |  
| 10:00  |    20       |  
| 11:00  |    15       |
```

Then I could write an HQL query:

```
select 'temperature' time temperature from WeatherStatistic
```

which would return

```
'temperature'  09:00   10
'temperature'  10:00   20
'temperature'  11:00   15
```

The first column is a string literal, the subsequent columns are time and the temperature value.

If the table is as follows:

```
| time   | temperature | humidity |  
 -------- ------------- ----------  
| 09:00  |    10       |   20     |
| 10:00  |    20       |   15     |
| 11:00  |    15       |   30     |
```

Is it possible to write a query (Criteria/HQL/SQL) to produce the results below?

```
'temperature'  09:00   10
'temperature'  10:00   20
'temperature'  11:00   15
'humidity'     09:00   20
'humidity'     10:00   15
'humidity'     11:00   30
```

If this can be done, is it then possible to provide the flexibility to allow any combination of fields value to be pulled out, ie: either temperature or humidity, or both?

The data is to be used for dynamic generation of time series graphs. I am working with a Hibernate data source for Jasper which takes in a HQL query string and feeds the query results directly up to Jasper which then outputs the generated graph images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you could use a union:

```
select * from 
    (select 'temperature' as label, time, temperatureas value from weatherstatistic
     union
     select 'humidity' as label, time, humidity as value from weatherstatistic)
order by label, time
```

You will have to construct this query dynamically before passing it to JasperReports.

Since HQL doesn't support union, I don't see a way to do it in HQL, though.

You could also fetch the data in your Java code before (using a simple HQL query), build a list of Java Beans containing a label, time and value, and use these as a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I should post the solution I actually came up after considering JB Nizet's suggestions!

I solved the problem by writing a custom Jasper-Hibernate data source that accepts a List of HQL queries. Under the hood, this data source executes the queries in series (effectively simulating a union) and concatenates the results together so that Jasper can access them sequentially.